Почему в консоли Пролога получаю False?
Создал на Прологе программу. Она разделяет список на два списка. Разделителем служит число N. Всё, что меньше N, отправляется в L1, всё, что больше - в L2. Программа:
% Предикат для разделения списка на два подсписка
split_list([], _, [], []).
split_list([X|L], N, L1, L2) :-
    X < N,
    split_list(L, N, [X|L1], L2).
split_list([X|L], N, L1, [X|L2]) :-
    X >= N,
    split_list(L, N, L1, L2).

Программу записал в файл split с расширением .pl "Блокнота". Файл поместил в рабочую папку.
Перешел в диалоговое окно для взаимодействия с Прологом. После приглашения к диалогу ?- ввел название файла:
?-[split].

Получил ответ Пролога True.
Далее ввел команду для загрузки программы из файла:
?- consult('split.pl').

Получил ответ Пролога True.
Затем ввел строку (не как комментарий, а в качестве кода):
?- split_list([1,2,3,4,5,6], 3, L1, L2).

Получил ответ Пролог False. В чем причина?
Использую версию SWI-Prolog

@Stanislav Volodarskiy, по первому предложению. Здесь у меня базовый случай рекурсии. Описывает, что произойдет, если входной список пуст ([]). В этом случае, независимо от значения N (обозначено «_») оба результирующих списка (L2 и L3) тоже будут пустыми. Рекурсия завершится

Исправил код следующим образом:
% Предикат для разделения списка на два подсписка
split_list([], _, [], []).
split_list([X|L], N, [X|L1], L2) :-
    X =< N, 
    split_list(L, N, L1, L2).
split_list([X|L], N, L1, [X|L2]) :-
    X > N,
    split_list(L, N, L1, L2).

Определил, что разделитель попадает в первый список. В итоге получил списки следующим образом:
?- split_list([1,2,3,4,5,6], 3, L1, L2).
L1 = [1, 2, 3],
L2 = [4, 5, 6]

